# (a mod 2*x)-(a mod x)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modulus

I am trying to find the possible values of this expression.

```
(a mod 2*x)-(a mod x)
```

I suspect they might be 0 or x, but I'm really not sure. I can't seem to be able to write down a proper argument.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Agreed that math.se is the place to go. And yes, the possible values are 0 and x, assuming a and x are both positive.

Comment: But could you tell me why?

Comment: Sure. Let `a` have the form `a = p*x + b`. Then `a mod x` is `b` and `a mod 2*x` is `b` if  `p = 2*r` (`a = 2*r*x + b = (2*x)*r + b`) and `x+b` if `p = 2*r + 1` (`a = (2*r + 1)*x + b = 2*r*x + x + b = (2*x)*r + x + b`. Thus the difference is either `b - b = 0` or `(x + b) - b = x`.

Comment: @DocMax, you could still make this comment an answer, even if you consider m.s.e the better place. Just to get this out of the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @MvG: Good point. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the possible values are 0 and `x`, assuming that both `a` and `x` are positive. The logic is as follows.

Let `a` have the form

```
a = p*x + b
```

Then it is easy to see that `a mod x = b`.

For `a mod 2*x`, if `p = 2*r` (`p` is even) then

```
a = 2*r*x + b = (2*x)*r + b
```

so that `a mod 2*x = b` and `p = 2*r + 1` (`p` is odd) then

```
a = (2*r + 1)*x + b = 2*r*x + x + b = (2*x)*r + x + b
```

so that `a mod 2*x = x + b`. Combining these results, the difference is either `b - b = 0` (when `p` is even) or `(x + b) - b = x` (when `p` is odd).